# How to obtain the environment variables of a process started by systemctl?

Tags: linux, systemd, environment-variables, systemctl

### Question

Given a `systemctl` template and unit file as follows, I am trying to obtain the environment variables that will ultimately be passed to a process on start (regardless of whether the service is currently running):

`/etc/systemd/system/example-template@.service`

```
...
[Service]
Environment="VAR1=val1"
Environment="VAR2=val2"
...
```

`/etc/systemd/system/example-template@example-unit.service.d/unit.conf`

```
[Service]
Environment="VAR2=Overridden by %i"
```

---

After exploring the options offered by `systemctl` I haven't been able to find anything other than `systemctl show example-template@example-unit --property=Environment`, the output of which contains the variables as a single string:

```
Environment=VAR1=val1 VAR2=Overridden by example-unit
```

However as it contains no convenient delimiter I would prefer to avoid having to parse this to recover the original variables.

Originally I had thought to utilise the `EnvironmentFile` directive by moving the variables into their own files and sourcing them from my script. Unfortunately at least one of my variables requires the `%i` parameter expansion which is not performed on those defined in an `EnvironmentFile`.

Is there a better way to achieve what I need?

### Context

We have 80 Tomcat instances which have been migrated from an OpenSUSE server to a CentOS 7 server. Historically these have been managed via a System V init script which was cloned for each instance. The init scripts are functionally identical, but differ by the values they export before delegating start/stop commands to the `catalina.sh` script shipped with Tomcat. Updating any common functionality requires applying the change to all 80 files.

In addition to this we have a wrapper script which delegates to `catalina.sh`, adding such options deleting deployed files or tailing log files. This is the script which requires knowledge of the environment variables; currently these are exposed by invoking the init script with particular arguments, whether the server is running or not.

Instead of sticking with System V and consolidating the common functionality into a single sourceable script (my original intention), I decided to migrate to `systemd` to take advantage of its support for unit file templates as they seemed designed with this scenario in mind. This would allow me to globally define our default Tomcat settings while allowing individual instances to override certain variables (e.g. to increase JVM memory or test an applciation against a new version of Tomcat). The environment variables unique to each instance include such things as the PID file (which `catalina.sh` needs to be made aware of) and Tomcat base (config) location.

With that in mind the issue I'm facing is that the aforementioned wrapper script would no longer have access to the environment variables for a Tomcat instance (for example one of the variables is the `CATALINA_HOME` path which contains the deployed applications, logs, and config files for the server). Some of the functions of the script do not require the server to be running (such as cleaning a stopped server), so obtaining the environment from the process is not viable.

Now I could make the wrapper script derive (guess) this information from the unit name, or forego running the Tomcat servers as a service entirely by making the wrapper script invoke the `catalina.sh` script directly; however I was hoping to have the sole source of information about the service be the service itself, and also be able to utilise some of the features of `systemd` such as automatically restarting the service if it enters a failed state.

### Version Info

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810
- systemd 219
- bash 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: "Is there a better way to achieve what I need?" ... why do you need the environment variables? You have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so start with how you ended up at this problem.

Comment: @muru I have added a context section for background info

Comment: you can obtain the environment of *any* process with `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/<PID>/environ`.

Comment: If the service is logging properly, getting logs is easy: `journalctl -u foo@instance`.  I imagine similar better ways could exist for the rest of your wrapper script's functionality.

Comment: @UncleBilly my apologies, I had not included that some of the wrapper functions do not require the server to be running. Question updated.

Comment: @muru these are manual Tomcat installs rather than from RHEL (which I would assume would be logging properyl) so this isn't currently configured but I will look into it, thanks. The more custom stuff I can get rid of the better.

Comment: The environment is a property of a process. If you do not have a process, you have no environment. Are you looking for a guess of an environment, which might exist hopefully?

Comment: @ceving I suppose I'm looking for what the environment _would be_ if you started the process using the unit configuration on disk at that particular moment, provided it isn't already running (in which case I could use Uncle Billy's suggestion). `systemctl show` does actually provide that, just not in a particularly useable format.

Comment: Note in my systemd version 231, values from `systemctl show ... --property=Environment` are shown with spaces converted to `\x20`, so you can split the output on space to get the `var=value` parts.

Comment: @meuh that would certainly make using the ouput from `show` much more viable, presuming any spaces that are part of the values themselves are preserved. I'm already on the latest `systemd` version from the repos we are using, hopefully that update will be in the next minor RHEL release towards the end of this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently completed a migration like this.

Defaults that apply to all units go in Environment= directives in the template file.  EnvironmentFile=production.%i.env is used to load per-instance overrides.

Don't worry that you can't use %i in production.foo.env. Just hardcode "foo" in that file. That can be automated if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That will work as long as none of the variables that the script needs to know about require a default, as otherwise I can just source the `.env` file. I will need to analyse the script a bit closer to confirm whether that is the case.